# How to match strings with matching group to extract values?

Tags: java, regex

I have source string `"This is my test string"` and would like to extract a value of it using a specific pattern: `"{0} is my {1} string"`

I'd like to extract eg `This` and `test` here. How do I write that with regex matching group?

The following is some kind of pseudocode I came up with. But I don't know exactly how to implement these matching groups:

```
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("(.*) is my (.*) string").matcher("This is my test string");
if (match.matches()) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= match.groupCount(); i++) {
        Sysout(match.group(i));
    }
}
```

prints:

```
This is my test string
This
test
```

But I'd like to get:

```
This
test
```

How can I prevent to take the whole string as a matching group? Or could I as well directly bind a match to a specific matching group?
Like `{1} is my {0} string` where `test` would go to `match.group(0)`? Is that possible?

Comment: You should start your `i` at 1, not 0. `.group(0)` always returns the full text matched by the matcher. Also, it _should_ print `test` in the output since your regex matches the input.

Comment: OK I see. yes it also prints `test`, adapted my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the group index problem mentioned in the comment, there is another question:

> [...] could I as well directly bind a match to a specific matching group? Like {1} is my {0} string where test would go to match.group(0)? Is that possible?

Not with Java 6. With Java 7+, you can use named capturing groups:

```
Pattern.compile("(?<first>.*) is my (?<second>.*) string")
```

You can then use `.group("first")` and `.group("second")` on your `Matcher` instance.

Note that `.group()` is equivalent to `.group(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

group 0 is ALWAYS the whole matched string. matching groups that you define within a regexp always start from 1.

have a loot at the [javadoc for Matcher.group(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29):

> Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is
>   equivalent to m.group()